# Extending the DataAnnotations attributes for MVC in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Brad Willson has a great article on descripting how to use DataAnnotations.  http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/dataannotations-and-aspnet-mvc.html What I would like to do is extend the available attributes that I can use.   Something like [ PastDate(you must enter a date in the past)]  or [InvoiceNumber( all invoices start with INV and end with 002)].    I know that I could use the Regular expression attribute to accomplish this.    However having more descriptive attributes would be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class that inherits from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute` and then use that attribute like this :

```
public class yourModel {
    [CustomValidation(typeof(yourClass), "yourMethod")]
    public int yourProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Haven't tried it but it should work.

Comment: Yes, any attribute which derives from ValidationAttribute will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few of these in my project - some still use regular expressions, but at least this way they're only in one place:

```
public class TelephoneAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public TelephoneAttribute()
        : base(@"^\(?(\d{3}\)?)((-| )?\d{3})(-?\d{4})$") { }
}
```

And more like what your example:

```
public class MinimumDateAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public MinimumDateAttribute(string MinimumDate)
        : base(typeof(DateTime), MinimumDate, DateTime.MaxValue.ToShortDateString()) { }
}
```